# How would I solve for a rate that compounds m times per annum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Please excuse me, this is my first time using the site and I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing with the notation. Anyways, I am attempting to prove that:

$$R_m = m\left(e^{\frac{R_c}{m}}-1\right)$$

Where...

$$R_c = m\left(ln\left({1+\frac{R_m}{m}}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$e^{\frac{m(ln(1+\frac{R_m}{m}))}{m}} \rightarrow e^{ln(1+\frac{R_m}{m})} \rightarrow 1+\frac{R_m}{m}$

Plugging it back into the larger equation

$m(1+\frac{R_m}{m}-1) \rightarrow R_m$

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange Flyance and Kevin Pei! Overall, great answer, but perhaps try to leave some intuition of the process or some explanation of how you get to your initial step next time. Because of the specific question, your answer did its job though and providing more information may have been overkill. Anyways, hope you both enjoy the site!